# Changing an ImageResource (drawable) programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am currently using the `@android:drawable/presence_online` as the srcCompat for a ImageView.

I would like to change it programmatically to `@android:drawable/presence_offline`.

I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
    final ImageView imgPresence = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPresence);
    imgPresence.setImageResource(R.drawable.presence_offline);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't that be setImageResource(android.R.drawable.presence_offline) ?

Comment: @Srijith Please post an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed `android` in the resource id.

Instead of

`imgPresence.setImageResource(R.drawable.presence_offline);`

use this:

```
imgPresence.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.presence_offline);
```

Answer (score 2):

Though commented by @Srijith, I am putting as an answer here:

Change the below line

```
 setImageResource(R.drawable.presence_offline);
```

to

```
setImageResource(android.R.drawable.presence_offline);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
imgPresence.setImageResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.presence_offline));
```